# Why do I getting not full response from server?

Tags: sockets, winsock

I wonder, why do I get not full response from my server ( Win ) to show its in client ( *nix )/

Herer are the codes:

```
Server ( Win ) : http://pastebin.com/CC1EHj0N<br />
Client ( *nix ) : http://pastebin.com/bFiLjMHh
```

The request from client ( "Hello from Gentoo!" ) my server gets well, but the response which sending to client isn't rendering full at client side.

As you see, I used:

```
char response[]
```

And then sizing it with sizeof() in send method.

In the debugger, I'm getting result well, that must sending all sizedof bytes.

But in client , I'm getting not all string :(

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) 2 problems with your code:

- In your client your buffer is smaller than the message sent by the server. Thus, **it's inherently impossible to receive the entire message in one go**
- You're receiving only once. Nothing prevents `TCP` from handing you the bytes one by one. **TCP is stream-oriented**, even if you're providing enough space (which you're not)

To expand on the first point:

- you send this message from the server

  ```
  char response[] = "Hello from Windows 7 Home Basic!\r\n";`
  result = send(sock_cli, response, sizeof(response), 0);
  ```
- this is your receive buffer:

  ```
  char mess[] = "Hello from Gentoo!\r\n";
  char buffer[sizeof(mess)];
  /* ... */

  recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(mess), 0);
  ```

For starters, you could ensure that the client tries to `recv` in a buffer that's at least as large as the largest message sent by the server. But the true solution would be to `recv` in a loop.